# Making a thread wait for another thread to finish the execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

Thread newbie here, In the following code I want thread A to finish first and then the thread B. Right now, both the main thread waits for both the threads to finish their execution. How can I make thread B wait till thread A finishes execution. I am not trying to achieve anything, it's just a simple coding exercise that I saw in a book.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void run1()
{
    cout << "Facebook " << endl;
    cout << "Facebook: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}

void run2()
{
    cout << "Twitter " << endl;
    cout << "Twitter: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}
int main()
{
    thread A(run1);
    thread B(run2);
    A.join();
    B.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The output must be:

> Facebook 
>  Facebook: some_thread_id 
>  Twitter 
> Twitter: some_thread_id

Comment: Pass a reference to a thread, that the thread needs to wait on, to the thread that needs to do the waiting?

Comment: In thread B wait for A to complete.

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet for the same?

Comment: You already have the appropriate `join` call. Just move it inside `run2`, and then figure out how to pass in a reference to the thread. At least _try_.

Comment: @Useless I am unable to figure it out that's why I asked here

Comment: You could also just not start thread B until after `A.join()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void run1()
{
    cout << "Facebook " << endl;
    cout << "Facebook: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}

void run2(thread *toBeWaited)
{
    cout << "Twitter " << endl;
    cout << "Twitter: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;

    toBeWaited->join();
}

int main()
{
    thread A(run1);
    thread B(run2, &A);
    B.join();
    return 0;
}
```

In a real world scenario you must ensure the lifetime of the A thread. You could also start thread A inside B or wait for A to complete before you start A. That depends on your actual scenario which is best.